# Does CFMutableBitVectorRef need to be explicitly released?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, core-foundation

As far as I can tell, foundation types that start with CF are C types and thus are not reference counted, is that correct? But as far as I can tell, there's no specific CFBitVectorRelease function.

I'm assuming they need to be released by calling `CFRelease`, would that be correct?

Comment: Yes, no, and yes. They are C types (Core Foundation is a C API, i.e. no objects). It is a form of reference counting. (The number of retains are matched agains the number of releases, but the framework generally doesn't do this automatically and has no concept of an auto-release pool.) If a type does not have a specific `CFRelease*()` function, use `CFRelease`.

Comment: @JamesBucanek Thanks. Can you write it as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Core Foundation is a C API; there are no language-level objects.

So while CF "Types" are not classes/objects, they act like objects (and several are actually interchangeable with Objective-C and Swift objects). Among their shared traits, they have reference counting (balancing the number of retains against the number of releases until they match and the type/object is deallocated).

But since this is C, there is no built-in, automatic, or implied reference counting (e.g. ARC). So you're required to manually retain the type until you no longer need it, at which time you must call `CFRelease` to dispose of it. And Core Foundation does not have auto-release pools.

Some types have a specific `CFReleaseThisType()` function. If a type has no specific release function, use `CFRelease()`.

It's all spelled out in the [Core Foundation Memory Management](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/CFMemoryMgmt.html) guide.